# Elastic Node On local in 6.2

Tags: elasticsearch, junit, elasticsearch-6

How to start localhost elasticsearch node in my junit test, and use  high level rest client( Elasticsearch 6.2.)

Here is the code I tried

```
String clusterName = "test";
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
        .put("path.home", ES_WORKING_DIR)
        .build();
new Node(settings).start();
```

and  the error is.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported transport.type []

Answer (score 1):

Embedded Elasticsearch node is not supported anymore.
You can read here for more detail
[Embedded Elasticsearch not supported](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-the-server)

Btw, in case you still want to have that feature (run component integration test, for example), there're some third-parties library may support you:

- https://github.com/allegro/embedded-elasticsearch
- https://github.com/nitishgoyal13/elasticsearch-6-embedded-cluster